# Invalid operand for offset

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

Given I have this array: FOO BYTE 1,2,3,4

And, I want to pass an an array to a procedure using the stack.

My question is if I want to pass at index that is not 0 (for example the 2 in my array) I can do the following: push OFFSET foo[1]... but this does not work (compile error): push OFFSET foo[eax] with eax being 1.

Does any register work in the brackets, so I don't have to use a constant? I want the index to change based on user input, because then I would not have to use a series of if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the address first by using some form of addition, then put that value on the stack. One possible solution:

```
lea edx, [foo+eax]
push edx
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for this is:

```
        push    offset foo+2
```

Note that the immediate added to an offset ignores the data type of foo (it wouldn't matter if foo was a DWORD, adding 2 always adds 2, without any scaling effects).